# Escape-backspace behavior in fish shell like in other shells

Tags: shell, fish

I recently started using the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) for some things and generally like it. However I've run across one situation that would be great if there were a workaround. Say I typed a command like this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname
```

(bonus points if you recognize where that's from :) )

In typical *nix shells like bash, if I hit **Esc** then **Backspace**, it will erase back to the previous non-alphanumeric character (in this case the hyphen after "local") so you can basically go a "word at a time" deleting commands.

In fish shell, hitting Escape before Backspace does nothing special compared to just hitting Backspace (erases the previous single character only). Is there a way to do "by-word backspacing" in fish shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my reading of the fine [manual](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#editor), it looks like Ctrl-W might do what you want.

Comment: Hey look, that works! Thanks for the link (and the nice way of saying "RTFM"!)

Answer (score 0):

They're slightly different. <kbd>esc</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> deletes an element, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> deletes to the previous whitespace (or space character).